# How to update cart item and cart summery data on cart page in Hyva theme or Alpine js ajax response?

Tags: magento2, hyva, alpine.js

How to reload cart item and cart summery data on cart page in Hyva theme or Alpine js ajax response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ARJUN Try this in your ajax response.

```
function reloadCartContent() {
    window.fetch(window.location.href, {
        method: "GET"
    }).then((result) => {
        return result.text()

    }).then((body) => {
        hyva.setCookie('mage-cache-sessid', '', -1, true);
        window.checkoutConfig = null;
        hyva.replaceDomElement('#maincontent', body)

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        window.location.reload()
    })
}
```